# How do I bind dynamic byte array to button background in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a custom control that has a specific set of values on it. Also it has some custom events. I've been trying to get my byte array (blob) that I get from the database into my Custom Control background (button).

```
<Button  Width="{Binding x}" Height="{Binding y}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="100" Margin="1" FontSize="100" >
    <Image Source="{Binding image_link}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="{Binding x}" Width="{Binding y}" />
</Button>
```

And my custom control:

```
[JsonProperty("consoleButton.id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("consoleButton.parent_id")]
    public int? parent_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("consoleButton.console_id")]
    public int console_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("consoleButton.image_link")]
    public byte[] image_link { get; set; }

    public string website_link { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("consoleButton.tag_name")]
    public string tag_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("consoleButton.button_type")]
    public Miscellaneous.Enums.buttontype button_type { get; set; }

    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    //public string name { get; set; }

    public BitmapImage brush { get; set; }


    public ImageButton(int id, int? parent_id, int console_id, byte[] image_link, string website_link, string tag_name, Miscellaneous.Enums.buttontype button_type, int x, int y, double convertSize)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.id = id;
        //this.name = "btn" + id.ToString();
        this.parent_id = parent_id;
        this.console_id = console_id;
        this.image_link = image_link;
        this.website_link = website_link;
        this.tag_name = tag_name;
        this.button_type = button_type;
        this.x = Convert.ToInt32(x * convertSize);
        this.y = Convert.ToInt32(y * convertSize);

        BitmapImage btm;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image_link))
        {
            btm = new BitmapImage();
            btm.BeginInit();
            btm.StreamSource = ms;
            // Below code for caching is crucial.
            btm.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            btm.EndInit();
            btm.Freeze();
        }
        brush = btm;
    }
```

I've tried a few thing as you can see (added extra code) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are the `x` and `y` Bindings working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind a UserControl's UI elements to own properties of the UserControl, you'll have to set the control instance as source object of the Binding.

One way to do that is to set the `RelativeSource` property:

```
<Image Source="{Binding image_link,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" .../>
```

Note that you do not need an extra ImageSource (or BitmapImage) property like your `brush` property. WPF provides built-in type conversion, which will automatically convert `byte[]` to `ImageSource`.

---

Since your control's properties do not fire a change notification, it may also be necessary to set their value before calling `InitializeComponent`:

```
public ImageButton(...)
{
    ...
    this.image_link = image_link;
    ...
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Changed code to `<Button  Width="{Binding x}" Height="{Binding y}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="120" Margin="5" FontSize="100" >
        <Image Source="{Binding image_link, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Height="270" Width="240" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Button>` and put the `InitializeComponent();` on the bottom of the constructor but nothing appeared yet.

Comment: On second note it seems to work! (Somehow the picture is hidden when the button is smaller?) But since your code works I will mark it as answered! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the wrong property from what i can tell: Source="{binding image_link} when I believe it should be Source="{binding brush}

(Tiny restructuring of code btw):

```
    BitmapImage btm = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image_link))
    {
        ms.Position = 0;
        btm.BeginInit();
        btm.StreamSource = ms;
        btm.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        btm.EndInit();
    }
    btm.Freeze();
    brush = btm;
```

Comment: I added brush as binding `Image Source="{Binding brush}"` like so, but i get no different result (just a grey button).

Comment: have you verified your BitmapImage is actually valid and being created?

Comment: Well the byte array is a valid byte array, because i built the entire application before but in WinForms and there I used `(Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(image_link));` within the memory stream.

Comment: The "restructuring of code" makes no sense. Where is the functional difference to the original code? Setting `ms.Position = 0` is redundant, because the MemoryStream was just created.

Comment: For `{Binding image_link}` vs `{Binding brush}`, the former should also just work, because built-in type conversion does actually convert from `byte[]` to `ImageSource`. Hence the whole `brush` property and the BimatImage craetion code is redundant.